# When can we use normal approximation?

Tags: probability

It sounds stupid to ask this question, but from the definition of the central limit theorem: Let $X_1, X_2, ... $ be a sequence of independent random variables having mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and the common distribution function F and

"moment-generating function $M$ defined in a negiborhood of zero".

Here is the question I want to ask, how can we check this neighborhood (for example a Poisson distribution)?

I know that we can easily assume it is okay for $n\geq30$, but I want to say it more formly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're interested in Berry Esseen bounds. The simplest result says that if

$Z_n:=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}},$

and $F_n(z)$ is the cdf of $Z_n$, then

$$|F_n(z)-\Phi(z)|\leq \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}},$$

where $\rho=E[|X_1|^3]$, the third moment (notice that this requires the third moment to exist). $C$ is a constant, whose best current upper bound is $C<0.5$. And, $\Phi(z)$ is the normal cdf.

For example, if you have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then $\rho=O(\lambda^3)$, meaning that if say, $n=30$ then $C\rho/\sigma^3\sqrt{n}\approx 0.5/5.5\approx 0.07$, which seems decent.

The basic takeaway from this is that the error in the approximation to the normal distribution drops off like $\sqrt{n}$, so if you have a relatively small third moment, then you'll have a good approximation for $z$ small, say $|z|<3$, which is within 3 standard deviations of the mean 0.

However, this approximation is *not* reliable for $z$ far away from $0$, the mean. This is because even though $|F_n(z)-\Phi_n(z)|$ is small (because individually the *densities* $f_n(z)$ and $\phi_n(z)$ are small), one could still have $F_n(z)/\Phi_n(z)$ be really large or small. If you're interested in this, read about "fat-tail distributions" which commonly come up in finance for example. The moral is that the central limit theorem is good for predicting *typical* values of $Z_n$ but tends to become much worse if you're wondering about the probability of rare events.

Comment: @user131605: This very nice answer does not help judge when you can use normal approximations for tail probabilities (as noted in the last paragraph), but it focuses very nicely and explicitly on the importance of skewness (as illustrated in a couple of my examples). Also, Berry-Esseen is an important theorem in probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended Comment, not an answer. Actually, I'm not
sure there *is* an answer along the lines you seek. First, although
the proof of the CLT is in terms of MGFs, I'm not sure MGFs
are going to be helpful judging how well sums or averages of
iid observations match the normal distribution. Second, the
$n \ge 30$ rule is often quoted and, in my experience, seldom helpful.

Roughly speaking the CLT often works for surprisingly small $n,$
especially if the distribution of the $X_i$ is (close to) symmetrical
and without 'fat' tails.

**Example 1.** Sums of variables $X_i \sim Unif(0,1)$ are very
close to normal for very small $n.$ In the early days of computer
simulation $Z = \sum_1^{12} X_i - 6$ was often used to simulate
standard normal data. Such values have $E(Z) = 0$ and $V(Z) = 1.$
Although they necessarily have support $(-6,6),$ that does not
matter much because standard normal has only minuscule probability
outside that interval. (Nowadays when trig and log functions
are quickly executed, an exact method using such functions is
used to simulate standard normal variates; Google 'Box-Muller transformation', if interested.)

The brief R program below generates 1000 'standard normals' in this way. As expected the average is near 0 and the sample variance is near 1.
A Shapiro-Wilk test of normality for our first couple of runs could
not distinguish the sequence from a normal sample (P-values about .73 and about .12.)

```
 m = 1000;  u = runif(12*m)
 DTA = matrix(u, nrow=m)  # 1000 x 12 matrix
 z = rowSums(DTA) - 6
 mean(z);  var(z)
 ## 0.01051165
 ## 1.025977
```

However, agreement can be quite bad even for relatively large $n$ if the $X_i$ are skewed and or have heavy tails. Of course, the CLT does not apply to Student t random variables with DF = 1 or 2 (nonexistent variance). And convergence is extremely slow for $T(3)$ because of heavy tails.

**Example 2.** If the $X_i$ are exponential, we have an extremely
skewed distribution with a fat right tail. For such variables,
the CLT does not 'work' satisfactorily even for $n  = 100.$ 
Sums of 100 exponentials are gamma with shape parameter 100
and thus skewness 0.2. Sums from the program below (with $X_i \sim Exp(rate=1)$) typically
give histograms that show noticeable skewness and results from
almost all our runs failed the Shapiro-Wilk test for normality.

```
 m = 1000;  x = rexp(100*m)
 DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # 1000 x 100 matrix
 z = rowSums(DTA)
```

**Example 3.** You asked specifically about what the CLT has
to say about Poisson distributions. The sum of $n$ Poisson variates with mean $\lambda$ is Poisson with mean $n\lambda.$ Agreement with a normal distribution
depends on $n\lambda.$ If $n=100$ and $\lambda = .1,$ then agreement will be horrible. If $n = 10$ and $\lambda = 25,$ then agreement
will be pretty good for most applications. Clearly, no rule-of-thumb about $n$ makes
any sense unless you specify $\lambda.$

Specifically, if $X \sim Pois(225),$ then $P(X \le 250) = 0.9535$ and the appropriate normal approximation with continuity correction is $0.9554.$ But if $X \sim Pois(10),$ then $P(7 \le X \le 9) =  0.3278,$ whereas the normal approximation is only $0.3030.$

In practical applications, exact
computations with statistical software have pretty much replaced
CLT approximations.